# How can the Firefox 35 search option for a match to be case sensitive be set to global?

Tags: firefox, search

Previously, the setting *Match Case* for the find facility (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) in Firefox was ***global*** - if the setting was changed in one window/tab, it would be the same in all other windows. This changed with the update to [Firefox 35](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/35.0/releasenotes/). Is there a way to make to the *Match Case* setting global, as in versions prior to Firefox 35?

The setting *Match Case* works as expected. It is just that now case-sensitive search must be set in each and every tab where it is needed as the setting always starts out as case insensitive.

[image: Screenshot from Firefox 35, display the options for]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that the (global) setting is ***no longer*** affected (Firefox 35 and later) by changing it in the find facility itself. Instead, it has to be done through the *about:config* mechanism:

1. Enter *about:config* into the address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Accept the warning message.
3. Type "case".
4. Double click on the entry ***accessibility.typeaheadfind.casesensitive*** in the list to open the *Enter integer value* dialog.
5. Change the number to 1 for case-sensitive search and press the *OK* button (or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

[image: Screenshot from Firefox, showing how to change accessibility.typeaheadfind.casesensitive]

The new setting immediately affects all tabs. There is no need to close the *about:config* window as it may soon be desired to change the (global) setting back to 0.